# Subdivide armature not looking right

Tags: armature

I'm playing around with the Animal Crossing 3D models, specifically the cat model. The current model has 1 bone for the ear. (Picture 1)
[image: Picture 1 - Current model only has 1 bone on the ears]

I want to make the ears fold over, so I tried subdiving the bone but I can't seem to get it to look right. The mesh didn't respond when I tried moving the new 2nd bone. (Picture 2)

[image: Picture 2 - Subdivided existing bone to create a new bone, mesh does not respond when move new bone]

so I tried going into Object Data Properties to assign the new bone in the Vertex Groups section to the mesh. The mesh now moves with the new bone, but it will detach itself from the head, which is not what I want. I'd like to anchor it to the head, like how the original artist made the model did. Could anyone teach me the right way to do this? (Picture 3)
[image: Picture 3 - Mesh moves with new bone after assigning vertex groups, but not in the way I want it to]

Comment: what do you mean by "it will detach itself from the head"? You need to make sure that the vertices that are assigned to the new vertex group has been removed from the other vertex group

Comment: Hi again! As u can see from the 3rd picture, when I move the new bone, the entire ear moves along with it and the causes the ear to separate from the head...... How do I get the ear to anchor in place? I just need the tip of the ear to fold over...

Comment: I don't know what happened, but if the new bone make everything move, select all the vertices that are not supposed to move in Edit mode in the 3D view, select the vertex group of the new bone in the Vertex Groups list and click on the Remove button so that all these vertices are removed from this group

Comment: Once again... THANK YOU!!! Why didn't I think of that -_-

Comment: Because I guess it's not obvious at the beginning  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the new bone make everything move, select all the vertices that are not supposed to move in *Edit* mode in the 3D view, select the vertex group of the new bone in the *Vertex Groups* list and click on the *Remove* button so that all these vertices are removed from this group.